# Call partial file name in a linux script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have several files: one_001_three.txt, one_002_three.txt, . . .

After removing the extension, I would like to call it such that:

```
    ${fname}_001
```

would call the file 'one_001'

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement better, it is not clear what you want.

Comment: `fname=one; echo "${fname}_001"` produces `one_001`... Or perhaps you want something more like `x=one_001_three.txt; fname=${x%%_*}`? It's really not clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understood your Question ..

yu can use this command basename try with this and develop .

basename one_001_three.txt _three.txt -->this will give output as **one_001** .

the filename doesnt get changed though .

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, this is all I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your Question ..

you can use this command basename try with this and develop .

basename one_001_three.txt _three.txt -->this will give output as one_001 .

the filename doesnt get changed though